# Save data of variable of smart contract in js

Tags: solidity, remix

can anyone let me know how to save data of a variable of my smart contract in javascript variable. for example if i have a function in my smart contract and that function returns some value now how do i save that value in my javascript variable.

```
var propertycontractaddress=propertycontract.at('0x691d3fb44bc81b5e420946a0aba3d1d0555c0715');

var total;

propertycontractaddress.GetTotalNoOfProperties(function(error,result){

if(!error){

total=result;

 }else{

 console.error(error);
    }
  })
  console.log(total);


for(var i=1; i<=total;i++){

var table = document.getElementById("ListedPropertyTable");


 var row = table.insertRow(1);

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

propertycontractaddress.GetId(i,function(error,result)

{

    if(!error)

    {

    cell1.innerHTML = result;

console.log(result);

}

    else

    {

console.error(error);

}

});

propertycontractaddress.GetPrice(i,function(error,result)

{

if(!error)

{

cell2.innerHTML = result;

}

else

{

    console.error(error);

}

});

propertycontractaddress.GetType(i,function(error,result)

{

if(!error)

{

    cell3.innerHTML = result;

}

else

{

    console.error(error);

    }

});

propertycontractaddress.GetCityn(i,function(error,result)

{

if(!error)

{

    cell4.innerHTML = result;

}

else

{

    console.error(error);

}
                    });
}



 </script>
```

Comment: In Truffle: `var x = await myContract.myFunc()`. Or if you're on web3 1.x outside of Truffle, `var x = await myContract.methods.myFunc().call()`.

Comment: @goodvibration by myContract you mean the var myContract in which i have saved the contract address right?

Comment: Can't really refer to that question, nor to your original question, without you posting your code first (which you should have done so anyway).

Comment: @goodvibration i have a GetTotalNoOfUsers function in a contract which returns me total no of users. Now i want to save total number of users in javascript variable. for example var a

Comment: Post your code! (Please).

Comment: @goodvibration i have posted my code.

Comment: @goodvibration My intention is to get the total number of properties and use it in the for loop to get respective things of properties in my table from first property id to last property id.

Comment: You can start by indenting this piece of code in an appropriate manner, so that it becomes readable for others possibly willing to answer your question. Thanks.